# C++ iterator as argument in lambda function, assertion failed: "vector iterators incompatible"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stl, iterator

I encountered a strange behavior after calling an lambda function with iterator as argument. It produces an assertion fail "vector iterators incompatible".

My code looks something like this:

```
std::vector<LAYOUT> Layouts;
// fill vector...
auto it = Layouts.begin();
while (it != Layouts.end()) {
    // do something...
    auto fn= [Layouts] (auto i) -> void {
        while (i != Layouts.end()) { // <- ASSERTION RAISED HERE
            // do something...
            i++;
        }
    };
    fn(it);
    it++;
}
```

The assertion is raised in vector.h in

```
void std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>::_Compat(const _Myiter& _Right) const {
// test for compatible iterator pair
    if (this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont()) {
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible");
        _SCL_SECURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
    }
}
```

The question is why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

I took me a while to find the real problem here. The solution is simple: `Layouts` was not passed as reference in capture clause. So a copy of that vector was generated first. Then it is clear to understand that `Layouts.end()` iterator was no more compatible with the original vector iterator given as argument in lambda function.

The solution is to add the reference operator (&) in capture clause.

```
auto fn= [&Layouts] (auto i) -> void {
    while (i != Layouts.end()) {
        // do something...
        i++;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am referring to the article [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help other developers with this information and to remind me of the problem should I encounter this problem again.